# dynamically populate images in order with shared class in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have something like the below, mark-up wise. And I have an image folder with all the thumb images in order within 'thumb1, thumb2, thumb3' etc *(but about 100)*. I would like to populate starting with 'thumb1' as the first instance to populate first instance of thumb class and then downward, 2,3,4 etc - but without touching the mark-up. Can this be done with JS, can the order be detected; first instance = thumb1?

```
<div class="thumb"></div>
<div class="thumb"></div>
<div class="thumb"></div>
<div class="thumb"></div>
<div class="thumb"></div>
<div class="thumb"></div>
<div class="thumb"></div>
<div class="thumb"></div>
<div class="thumb"></div>
<div class="thumb"></div>
```

Comment: you want the thumb image inside the div?

Comment: Does the number of thumbs ever change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming to path to your thumbnails is static and known you can do it like this:

```
$('.thumb').each(function(index){
    var src = 'path/to/img/thumb' + index+1;
    var $img = $('<img />').attr('src', src);
    $(this).html($img);
});
```

- Iterate over every `div` with class thumbnail
- use the `index` of the element to refer the image (`+1` because the index is starting at 0)
- adding a new `img`-element to the div with the path set

Instead of [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) you can also use [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) or [`.prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) to add the `img` to your `div`.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nsrb9t6z/)**

---

**Reference**

[.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)